# Python ytmusicapi problems with exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I created a program in python that use the ytmusicapi, if i execute the program there is no problem, but if I create an .exe file with pyinstaller:    `pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  main.py`, and I execute the exe it shows me this error:
 `Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 139, in <module> File "main.py", line 56, in run File "main.py", line 112, in getUrl File "ytmusicapi\ytmusic.py", line 120, in __init__ File "gettext.py", line 592, in translation FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'base' [9896] Failed to execute script 'main-v2' due to unhandled exception!`
The line where I have the error is this `ytmusic = YTMusic()`, I can't remove this line or catch the exception, because this line is fundamental.[cmd execution of the exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waRww.jpg)

I didn't try to do nothing.

Comment: Have you tried one of these parameters specified in the library documentation?
https://ytmusicapi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-package-ytmusicapi-with-pyinstaller

Comment: Thank you so much, I added this paramater: --collect-all ytmusicapi to the pyinstaller command and it worked.

Comment: I will post it as an answer in order to help anyone with this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In order to package ytmusicapi properly with pyinstaller, you need to collect the library to your executable.

To do it, add the following parameters:

```
--collect-all ytmusicapi
```

See more at: [How do I package ytmusicapi with pyinstaller?](https://ytmusicapi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-package-ytmusicapi-with-pyinstaller)